# fortran array=0 not given values when optimized

Tags: optimization, fortran, initialization

I have a rather large code (>6000 lines)that with a problem that I try to illustrate with the following very simplified extract:

```
program TestFortran
implicit none
real, parameter                  ::  eps = 1d-30
real              ::  res
real              ::  tmp

call TestInitialisation(res,tmp)
if (res>0 .and. res <eps) then
  write(*,*) "res is small but not zero and tmp = ", tmp
  res = 0d0
else
  write(*,*) "res is zero and tmp = ", tmp
end if

contains

subroutine TestInitialization(output,out2)
real,intent(out)  ::  output
real,intent(out)  ::  out2
real              ::  origa(10,10)
real              ::  copya(10,10)
origa = 0d0
copya = origa
call TIS1(copya,output,out2)
end subroutine TestInitialization


subroutine TIS1(arr2d,ret,out2)
real,intent(in)   ::  arr2d(:,:)
real,intent(out)  ::  ret
real,intent(out)  ::  out2
integer           ::  ii

do ii = 1,size(arr2d,2)
  call TIS2(arr2d(:,ii),ii,ret,out2)
  if (ret > 0) then
    exit
  end if
end do

end subroutine TIS1

subroutine TIS2(arr1d,jj,ret,out2)
real,intent(in)   ::  arr1d(:)
real,intent(out)  ::  ret
real,intent(out)  ::  out2
integer           ::  ii
integer,intent(in)::  jj

do ii = 1,size(arr1d)
  ret = arr1d(ii)
  out2 = real(jj)
  if (ret > 0) then
    out2 = -1d0
    exit
  end if
end do
end subroutine TIS2
end program TestFortran
```

The real program does work as expected in debug mode. However, when in release mode (visual studio 2017 with intel compiler 2017), switch /O3, the `res` value is just  garbage (like 1.0831d-273, however I am unsure weather to trust the variable explorer when debugging optimized code). I could not recreate the situation with the example above, it just serves as illustration (the`tmp` variable is there for it not to just optimize the whole thing away). If I add a `write(*,*) "res in TIS2 =",res`in subroutine `TIS2` in the **real program** code, the result is correct, but this it not wanted (especially because of speed degradation).

I have tested various compiler flags compbinations; i.e. the following:

> /debug:full /O2 /Qinit:snan /Qinit:arrays /fpe:0  /Qipo /traceback
>   /check:uninit /arch:SSE3 /real_size:64 /fp:fast=2  /Qvec-threshold:60  /recursive

Does anyone have any hint's or comments on this?

Comment: "I could not recreate the situation with the example above" - please try to create an example which _does_ show a problem.  Without it, you're likely to get answers which are speculative only.

Comment: @francescalus - I know... I have tried but I do not know howto. The real program is large and it's really hard to boil down that code, unfortunately. However - even speculative answers/comments are appreciated.

Comment: The symptom you describe hints at variable being used before it has been given a value.  Some compilers, at debug level, will set variables to 0 but at higher optimisation levels will not.  I can't see that happening in the sample you have shown us but it's something you should investigate.  Your compiler may have an option to set values for all variables upon declaration, that might help you smoke out the issue.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't see any connection between the question and its title.

Comment: @High Performance Mark - thanks for your remarks. The title is connected to the code in `TestInitialization` where `origa = 0d0` and then the final `res` is not == 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a mistake (bug) where an array wasn't fully populated correctly. I found this using the compiler flags: `/Qinit:snan` together with `/Qinit:arrays` in debug mode. It did not show up in release mode.
So all in all it was just a fairly simple bug in my code that went unnoticed, mostly (in 99 % of the cases) everything went well, but not always. The strange thing was that it wasn't caught in release mode.